# minimax without choice

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, axiom-of-choice, maxima-minima

H. Komiya's elementary
[proof](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kmj/1138038812)
of Sion's minimax theorem seems not to use any transfinite induction or choice axiom. Is this really the case, or is it implicit there in some sneaky form? [If it really is the case, I guess it means that Hahn-Banach does not follow from minimax without some additional choice axiom.]

Comment: You might want to use better tags for this question. Something that will increase its exposure to people who are more familiar with using the minmax theorem and its proofs.